# Assigning a variable name in argument of function call

Tags: javascript, php, arguments

I've seen this before (or something similar) in some language and I'm guessing it was Javascript or PHP. I can't find anything related online - I'm guessing it's just that I don't know what it's called. Anyway, I'm wondering if I can do something like this:

```
function myFunc(t) {
    alert(t);
}
myFunc(alertString="foo");
```

Where the result of the function call would alert "foo".

Is this possible? My reasoning behind wanting to do something like this is that it improves readability without having to write line before the call to assign the variable. What is this called? Do any languages support this? I'm just interested in the idea. Thanks!

Comment: `myFunc("foo")` isn't sufficient? Naming the function properly usually provides all the self-documentation one needs. Or did I miss your point?

Comment: You missed the point. I know you can do that... I'm asking what what I'm trying to do is called.

Comment: Perhaps it is bad coding in and of itself to need to send a name, but I think it can improve readibility.

Comment: ...and yes, it's possible, as you'd see if you'd try it. However if you don't declare the variable, you'll create a global, which IMO isn't good.

Comment: If you know you can do that, then why did you ask *"Is this possible?"* and *"Do any languages support this?"*?

Comment: I think you are looking for named function parameters, not a variable assignment... This is not supported in either PHP or Javascript at this time AFAIK, but it is in languages such as C#. Here is a proposal to add them to PHP in a future version: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params

Comment: I think it's a better idea to rename your function to reflect what the arguments should be, otherwise its just unnecessary clutter with funciton arg names. I think python also supports named args

Comment: Oh, are you talking about assigning function arguments to their respective parameter by parameter name? If so, why are you using `alertString` instead of `t`?

Comment: Python: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/keywordArgs.html

Comment: I'm really just interested in learning more. I was aware of some of it to begin with and I just really wanted a name so that I could find out more about it. Thanks @DarkFalcon, that's sort of what I was talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments named-arguments aren't available *(yet)* in current versions of  *PHP* but as you stated, *"I've seen this before"* perhaps you simply meant you saw a value been assigned to a parameter in a function declaration?  ***i.e.*** this is just a *"default"* value if unspecified:

```
function foo($value = 'hello world!'){
    echo $value;
}

foo('bar'); //  bar
foo();      //  hello world!
```

---

If we are talking about named-arguments then this is not exactly the same but in both *PHP* and Javascript you will often see code where associative arrays or object maps are passed as a single argument to allow more flexibility where a function might accept several parameters.  *For example:*

***PHP***

```php
function foo($params){
    echo $params['a'] . $params['b'] . $params['c'];
}

foo(array(
  'a' => 'hello ',
  'b' => 'world',
  'c' => '!'
));
```

***Javascript***

```js
function foo(params){
    console.log(params.a + params.b + params.c);
}

foo({
   a: 'hello ',
   b: 'world',
   c: '!'
});
```

Comment: That last bit in the Javascript section was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It possible in PHP like this:

```
<?php
function test($t) {
    echo $t;
}

test($test="hi");
?>
```

That would assign the value "hi" to the variable `$test` which is then passed to the function `test()` ...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in JavaScript, using your own syntax. It is also possible in PHP, C# and Java. I'm not that knowledgeable in other languages. Thing is that `something = somethingElse` can be used as an expression, and the assignment operator usually doesn't only assign. He assign the value and then "leave behind" whatever value he had on his right-hand side.

Answer (score -1):

javaScript:

```
<script>
function myFunc(t) {
    alert(t);
}
myFunc("foo");

</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
function myFunc($t) {
   echo "<script> alert('$t')</script>";

}

myFunc('foo');

?>
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't make any sense.  Did you even read the question?